# Expected value in raffle tickets

Tags: probability

I know how to calculate expected value but the figures that I am getting are a bit meaningless to me.  For instance: If there is a prize value of 100.00, with a ticket price of $10.50 and 10 tickets being sold; each ticket purchased is an expected loss of .50.  Is there a way to pinpoint the optimal amount of tickets one should purchase? I hope this is clear (I am sure it's clear that I am not a math guy); this is merely curiosity.  Thanks!

Comment: The optimal number from the expectation point of view is $0$. The more you play the more (on average) you lose.

Answer (score 1):

You could argue with the Bernoulli principle, which states that you should maximize your "expected utility".  For that, you would have to know your "utility function", from which one can derive your degree of "risk aversion".

If you are "risk-neutral", then you will decide based on expected value only, and not buy any tickets, as in the previous answers.

If you are "risk averse", then you might even not participate in a raffle where the expected gain is positive, because your utility would rise less if you got the expected prize, than it drops if you don't win and lose the cost of the ticket, even if these are equal to or somewhat less (depending on your degree of risk aversion) than the expected prize.

You may be "risk-loving", in which case it's (almost) the opposite of the risk-aversion case - your utility would rise more if you got the expected prize than it drops when you don't win i.e. lose the cost of the ticket (if the latter are equal to the expected prize or even somewhat higher depending on your utility function).

So if you're risk loving, you might end up buying a ticket, or maybe 2, or 3...  depending on your degree of risk-aversion.  But even if you're extremely risk-loving, 9 would be the maximum number of tickets, because if you buy all ten, you have a certain loss.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_utility_hypothesis#Bernoulli.27s_formulation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion